# php include to external url

Tags: php, include

I am currently trying to use the php function 'include' to include an external url. This is so that whenever the webpage is updated it will automatically update mine. The trouble I'm having however is that I keep getting an error saying the following...

Warning: require() [function.require]: http:// wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by allow_url_include=0 in C:\wamp\www\starterpack\starterpack2\header.php on line 48

I have tried to find a way to fix this error or find a way around it but cannot find one. Does anyone have any ideas?

P.S I am building the site using wampserver, could permissions of the wampserver be causing this error?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Look at your php.ini and make sure allow_url_include is set to 1. Restart HTTPD, done.

Answer (score 10):

You would be better using `echo file_get_contents($url)` as the include statement could execute any PHP code returned by the other site.

Answer (score 5):

```
function getter($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $data;
}

echo getter('http://yourdomain.com/externalfile.php');
```

And you're done :)

Answer (score 0):

This will load an external website and also gives external links an absolute website link address

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.your_external_website.com");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$result = preg_replace("#(<\s*a\s+[^>]*href\s*=\s*[\"'])(?!http)([^\"'>]+)([\"'>]+)#",'$1http://www.your_external_website.com/$2$3', $result);
echo $result
```

Comment: Your answer is identical @squallstars.

Answer (score 0):

Look at your php.ini and make sure allow_url_include is set to 1

Otherwise use following ...

```
function getter($url) 
{
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
return $data;}
echo getter('http://yourdomain.com/externalfile.php');
```