# How to access class by including a URL?

Tags: php

I am a bit stuck.

Before proceeding I want to share some scripts. I have a class file in PHP which is this:

```
<?php

class db

{

private $dbn;    
private $port;    
private $uname;    
private $pwd;    
private $dbname;



function __construct(){

   /*  $this -> dbn ='localhost';    
    $this -> port ='3306';    
    $this -> uname = 'root';    
    $this -> pwd = '';    
    $this-> dbname = 'allindiacakes';*/



 /*  $this -> dbn ='localhost';    
    $this -> port ='3306';    
    $this -> uname = 'rombagif_floret';    
    $this -> pwd = 'Ashoke3';    
    $this-> dbname = 'rombagif_floret';*/        

     $this -> dbn ='localhost';    
    $this -> port ='3306';    
    $this -> uname = 'root';    
    $this -> pwd = '';    
    $this-> dbname = 'rombagif_floret';

}



public function getdbn(){

    return $this->dbn;    
}   

public function getPort(){

    return $this->port;    
}   

public function getUname(){

    return $this->uname;    
}



public function getPwd(){

    return $this->pwd;
}   

public function getDbName(){

    return $this->dbname;    
}      

public function getConnection(){

    $con ="'" .  $this->dbn . "','" . $this->uname . "','" . $this->pwd ."'";    
    echo $con;    
    return $con;    
}    
}    
?>
```

I am trying to include the URL of the class and then create a object like this.

In the `localhost/crack/index.php` file I did:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <?php 

          include 'http://localhost/rambagifts/logMeAdmin/functions/include/dbn.php'; 
          $d = new db();
          $dbname = $d->getdbn();
          echo $dbname;

        ?>

    </body>
</html>
```

But when I am calling `http://localhost/crack/`, I am getting the following error

> Fatal error: Class 'db' not found in `C:\xampp\htdocs\crack\index.php` on line 12

Comment: Should be directory path instead of URI

Comment: I actually get errors when I try this kind of shenanigan `include 'http://localhost/rambagifts/logMeAdmin/functions/include/dbn.php';`. I think you have to read the manual on includes in php

Comment: its taking from another remote url.............

Comment: hmmm... are you saying that your application does not reside in the same server?

Comment: Dont use remote file inclusion its vulnerable to external code injection. Use absolute paths like `C:/xampp/htdocs/rambagifts/logMeAdmin/functions/include/dbn.php`

Comment: You can not `include` a `PHP` file from another server (remote).

Comment: @RahilWazir what the... mixed slashes to get some file? is this even possible? I've never tried it for sure

Comment: yes i am including a file from another server, to a file in current server

Comment: Before doing coding it will better read this link http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

Answer (score 2):

From the php documentation: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

> If "URL include wrappers" are enabled in PHP, you can specify the file
>   to be included using a URL (via HTTP or other supported wrapper - see
>   Supported Protocols and Wrappers for a list of protocols) instead of a
>   local pathname. If the target server interprets the target file as PHP
>   code, variables may be passed to the included file using a URL request
>   string as used with HTTP GET. This is not strictly speaking the same
>   thing as including the file and having it inherit the parent file's
>   variable scope; the script is actually being run on the remote server
>   and the result is then being included into the local script.
>
> Note: Windows versions of PHP prior to PHP 4.3.0 do not support access
>   of remote files via this function, even if allow_url_fopen is enabled.

Especially the part saying "the script is actually being run on the remote server and the result is then being included into the local script". Your variables and class object definitions aren't echoed (good thing!) so they won't be included in your own script.

As others have said, do not include files from a URL, due to the URL being parsed and then included. You will need to include based on a local path or relative path so the php code itself will be included.

If you want to include a file from a different domain as was it in the same domain path. You can create a symbolic link (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link) to the other directory on the system. Which will allow you to include files from that directory locally.

For an example of how to use include on a remote URL; you can look at this question ([php include to external url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9196228/php-include-to-external-url)) where TS wants to include a remote (already parsed) header file.

Answer (score 0):

Your include now runs through the server; Get rid of the localhost, and use a file system path instead.