# Why will my URL include not work. allow_url_include is set to "On"

Tags: php, include

I have confirmed by running `phpinfo()` that the settings are "On" globally and locally.

```
allow_url_fopen On On 
allow_url_include On On
```

but when I do `include('http://www.example.com')`; I get a blank page, no errors, no error in the apache log, but script execution stops at the failed include.

If I do

```
$out=file_get_contents('http://www.example.com');
echo $out;
```

It works.

Comment: have you tried [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9196228/php-include-to-external-url)

Comment: @yate I did not access my php.ini file directly, but the output of phpinfo SHOULD be authoritative. Yes, Apache has been restarted.

Comment: What this really comes down to is "Is there a server or php setting that overrides `allow_url_include On On`?". The secondary question is, _if/since_ I don't intend for my "including" script to parse any of the "included" script's php, is there any reason NOT to use my workaround. `echo file_get_contents('http://www.example.com');`

Comment: `file_get_contents` is much more secure, you can also utilize [HTML Purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/) to prevent an XSS vulnerability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to my host, the answer was that the suhosin patch was preventing the url include.