# Include external html site after upgrading to php 7

Tags: php, php-7.2

I am trying to upgrade my php from v.5 to v.7.2, and I have encountered this bug I couldn't fix.
I have a tpl file with **external** header & footer included but they wont load anymore.
This is the error( * please note: spaces added on purpose * ) :

> Warning: include(): Failed opening 'https: //mywebsite.com/folder1/includes/wrappers/footer.html' for inclusion (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in * folderpath*\bottom_page.html on line 86

At the main tpl file (lets call it "home.tpl") I have this line for the footer:

```
<?php include dirname( __ FILE__)."\bottom_page.html" ;  ?>
```

At bottom_page.html I have some scripts which seems to be fine and at the end, this line:

```
<?php include('https: //mywebsite.com/folder1/includes/wrappers/footer.html'); ?>
```

this line seems to be the problem, I searched a lot and did not find a solution
This is what I have tried:

- verify  allow_url_fopen & allow_url_include in php.ini is 1
- using readfile or file_get_contents instead of include

Any more suggestions? :)

p.s: the url is correct, the browser shows the content I wanted to include..

Comment: Check the [allow_url_include](http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-include) setting

Comment: Don't use the fill URL for your include. Use the local path on the server. You're basically trying to go over the internet to get a file you already have on your server. And the php.ini for your new PHP version doesn't allow that.

Comment: @JohnConde by "local path on the server" do you mean using $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] ? because it doesn't work..
its value is the directory which bottom_page exists, and I actually need this address: https: //mywebsite.com/folder1/includes/wrappers

Comment: Try to remove the interval after "https:"

Comment: You don't have to use `$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]`. You can use any method that gets you the path to the correct file. It could be the full path or a relative path.

Comment: I don't think I'm getting through to you @JohnConde , do you mean using other $_SERVER['something'] parameters?
I don't believe it will help, the site address doesn't exists in the server, this address is external.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so I have found a solution- finally:

[php include to external url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9196228/php-include-to-external-url)

the comment from Nicholas Valbusa, the curl usage works :)